# Set sprite using background position

Tags: ios, random, background, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am new to cocos2d so please help me if u can

I have background moving from right to left, and the background contains small windows with 3 rows of windows

```
_spaceDust1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg_front_spacedust.png"];
_spaceDust2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg_front_spacedust.png"];

    CGPoint dustSpeed = ccp(0.1 , 0.1);
    CGPoint bgSpeed = ccp(0.05 , 0.05);

    [_backgroundNode addChild:_spaceDust1 z:0 parallaxRatio:dustSpeed positionOffset:ccp(0,winSize.height / 2)];
    [_backgroundNode addChild:_spaceDust2 z:0 parallaxRatio:dustSpeed positionOffset:ccp(_spaceDust1.contentSize.width , winSize.height / 2)];
```

Now add enemies wich also move from right to left with same speed

```
        _robbers = [[CCArray alloc] initWithCapacity:kNumAstroids];
    for (int i = 0; i < kNumAstroids; ++i) {
        CCSprite *asteroid = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"robber.png"];
        asteroid.visible = NO;
        [_batchNode addChild:asteroid];
        [_robbers addObject:asteroid];
    }
```

*in update method*:

```
      double curTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
   if (curTime > _nextRunemanSpawn) {
    float randSecs = [self randomValueBetween:0.20 andValue:1.0];
    _nextRunemanSpawn = randSecs + curTime;

    float randY = 80.0;
    float randY1 = 185.0;
    float randY2 = 293.0;
    float randDuration = [self randomValueBetween:5.2 andValue:5.2];
    float randDuration1 = [self randomValueBetween:1.0 andValue:1.0];

    CCSprite *asteroid = [_robbers objectAtIndex:_nextRobber];
    _nextRobber++;

    if (_nextRobber >= _robbers.count) {
        _nextRobber = 0;
    }
    //[asteroid stopAllActions];
    int winChoice = arc4random() % 3;
    if (winChoice == 0) {
        asteroid.position = ccp(winSize.width +asteroid.contentSize.width / 2 , randY);
        asteroid.visible = YES;

    }
    else if(winChoice == 1){

        asteroid.position = ccp(winSize.width +asteroid.contentSize.width / 2 , randY1);
        asteroid.visible = YES;

    }else {
        asteroid.position = ccp(winSize.width +asteroid.contentSize.width / 2 , randY2);
        asteroid.visible = YES;

    }



    [asteroid runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:randDuration position:ccp(-winSize.width-asteroid.contentSize.width, 0)],
                         [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setInvisible:)],nil]];
```

All is going well but i want to set this enemies in to window and in random position
so how can i set x-argument of enemies so it can be fix in to window of the background?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I cannot comment so this is written as an answer. What exactly are you trying to do? I am a bit confused. It sounds like you want the X position to be set so that it is in one of 3 random positions, is that correct?